# loginUser function is not submitting

Tags: reactjs, authentication

The following code is not submitting the username and password to my REST API. I don't get any error

```
import { Button, Container, Card, Form, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from 'react';

async function loginUser(credentials) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    })
      .then(data => data.json())
}

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUserName] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    
    const handleLogin = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const token = await loginUser({
                username,
                password
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Login error:', err);
        }
    }

    return (
        <Container className="mt-3">
            <Row className="justify-content-md-center mt-3">
                <Col md="2"></Col>
                <Col md="8">
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGroupUsername">
                                    <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="text" onChange={e => setUserName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Enter username" />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGroupPassword">
                                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="password"  onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" />
                                </Form.Group>

                                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col md="2"></Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

The code of the project is
https://github.com/jcheong/login-user-role-permission/tree/main

I try to use Chat GPT to see if there is anything wrong with code, and also try to understand similar code to compare

Comment: What specific debugging indication do you have that the AJAX request is not being made?  Can you clarify how you're observing the problem?

Comment: I'm monitoring on my rest api but not received any request, but on the browser I test some request on the api and it works fine

Comment: Check the browser console (through chrome devtools or otherwise) after you click on the button. Also double check the URL for the API.

Comment: Ok, I check the browser console and I get the following error

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: I install cors on the server and now I have communication between client and server. Now  I get the following error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)